# Is roxygen2 only for documenting R packages or also for R projects?

Tags: r, documentation-generation, roxygen2

I have a question about the ["roxygen2"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) package:

I have seen a lot of tutorials that make use of it for package documentation (such as the major ["object documentation"](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#roxygen-comments) page by Hadley Wickham)

So what if I do have R code that is not a package, say an R project?
**Can you document R Projects with roxygen2 as well?**

I was still able to run the 
`package.skeleton(name='RoxygenSkeleton', code_files = "Roxygen.R", force=TRUE)` function to create the basic package structure and .Rd files were created. But I would desire a nice output in HTML or PDF...

Comment: Since all you want is to generate HTML files, you could just generate the `*.Rd` files, then use [`tools::Rd2HTML`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/Rd2HTML.html). It's a bit spartan, but it meets your baseline requirement.

Comment: @r2evans “generate the *.Rd files” — how? As close as I can make out, this isn’t possible using roxygen2’s public API alone; see my answer.

Comment: I think I tried to accomplish something along the lines of what you're trying to do a few years ago.  Never completely finished the task but maybe it's of interest to you? https://github.com/Dasonk/flydoc And at the very least the method used in the `flyhelp` function might help get you there? https://github.com/Dasonk/flydoc/blob/master/R/flyhelp.R With that said the code is four years old at the moment so I don't make any guarantees that any of it still works

Comment: Since (per your discussion with @hadley) there is no way without a package structure, I thought using `Rd2HTML` would meet the last comment (*"I would desire a nice output in HTML"*), given that the OP has already created a skeleton package structure.

Comment: @Dason I think you should write an answer for this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe later but I haven't actually looked at that code in four years so I'm fuzzy on the details of what I did and how I got any of it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input everyone! I really appreciate it. @r2evans Yes I thought about using this workaround as well. It seems like for every function an own .Rd file is generated... so the documentation might be a bit clustered first, and then you could manually merge all files together.

Comment: @Dason - thanks, I will check out your package. It seems like a nice idea for a package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990228/1968), as of roxygen2 6.0, the following works to parse documented R source files outside packages.

```
source_env = roxygen2::env_file(sourcefile)
rd_blocks = roxygen2::parse_file(sourcefile, source_env)
help_topics = roxygen2::roclet_process(roxygen2::rd_roclet(), rd_blocks, source_env, dirname(sourcefile))
rd_code = lapply(help_topics, format)
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad! When using Roxygen with a project I saw that it only generated the "skeleton" (e.g. man-repository with .Rd in it) but did not really properly write out my comments in the respective .Rd files. Possibly that is due to using a "project" not "package". Thanks for showing us the workaround.