# creating Rd documentation files for R6 classes not in a package

Tags: r, function, roxygen2, r6

I am trying to create the documentation of a few scripts that have some R6 classes in it. As an example I use the R6Class named "Person" from here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/11/roxygen2-7-0-0/

I am using this function https://stackoverflow.com/a/59073260/12166017 to create the documentation without the need of creating a package. Is it also possible to use this for R6Classes or is there maybe another way to achieve this? With the mentioned function I always get an Error `R6 Class (Person) without source references.`

The solution of the official tidyverse blog https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/11/roxygen2-7-0-0/ to write `Roxygen: list(r6 = FALSE)` in the DESCRIPTION file does not work because I don't have a package and so no DESCRIPTION file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is to hijack some of roxygen2's unexported functions to create the block object for the documented R6 class and write an `Rd` file. This can then be parsed and written to html using the `tools` package.

This is a very rough proof-of-concept, requiring your R6 definition to be in a standalone file, and not taking any arguments to allow saving to specific locations, etc, but it could be adapted and expanded to suit:

```r
document_R6 <- function(R_file)
{
  blocks  <- lapply(roxygen2:::tokenize_file(R_file), roxygen2:::block_set_env,
                    env = .GlobalEnv)
  blocks  <- roxygen2:::order_blocks(blocks)
  roclet  <- roxygen2:::roclet("rd")
  my_rd   <- suppressWarnings(roxygen2:::roclet_process(roclet, blocks))
  my_rd   <- my_rd[[1]]$format()
  rd_file <- tempfile()
  writeLines(my_rd, rd_file)
  tools::Rd2HTML(tools::parse_Rd(rd_file), 
                 gsub("\\.R$", ".html", R_file))
}
```

So if we have the following file, taken from your link:

**Person.R**

```r
#' R6 Class representing a person
#'
#' A person has a name and a hair color.
Person <- R6::R6Class("Person",
  public = list(
    #' @field name First or full name of the person.
    name = NULL,

    #' @field hair Hair color of the person.
    hair = NULL,

    #' @description
    #' Create a new person object.
    #' @param name Name.
    #' @param hair Hair color.
    #' @return A new `Person` object.
    initialize = function(name = NA, hair = NA) {
      self$name <- name
      self$hair <- hair
      self$greet()
    },

    #' @description
    #' Change hair color.
    #' @param val New hair color.
    #' @examples
    #' P <- Person("Ann", "black")
    #' P$hair
    #' P$set_hair("red")
    #' P$hair
    set_hair = function(val) {
      self$hair <- val
    },

    #' @description
    #' Say hi.
    greet = function() {
      cat(paste0("Hello, my name is ", self$name, ".\n"))
    }
  )
)
```

Then we can do:

```r
document_R6("Person.R")
```

The following is a screenshot of the resulting rendered "Person.html" file, found in the same directory as "Person.R":

---

[image]